# Why does AdValify Return Animation Duration of Infinity for my Banner Animation

Tags: validation, animation, load, ads

I have a bunch of ads that I've created for an agency that need to pass this tool called Ad Valify. The people who serve the banners use Ad Valify to QA the banners. No matter what I do, Ad Valify returns a value of Infinite Animation Duration.

Sometimes when I remove one of the 3 main background images, the Animation Duration value becomes about 4 seconds. The ad is maybe 10 ish seconds give or take but definitely under 15 seconds.

I've uploaded the files here, https://fatimawork.com/300x250.zip